# Fast calculation of floating 1/N if factorization of very large integer N is known

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, performance, math

If I have integer number `N` that I know factorization of, what is the fastest (most efficient) way of computing `1/N` as a floating point number? Big floating (or integer) arithmetics should be used for that.

I want to do this in C++ (or to do experimental runs in Python).

My `N` is very huge, Giga/Tera-bits in size. Resulting floating point `N` should also have huge precision, around the same bit-size as initial `N`.

Precise floating value is needed meaning if I request floating precision `Log2(N)` bits then at least all `95%` leading bits of result should be precise (all same bits as in ideal value).

Of course instead of floating point computation one can compute `4^Ceil(Log2(N)) / N` as integer division, if it helps and/or simplifies task. For me these two tasks (integer and float) are essentially same, because integer representation is convertible to floating and vice versa.

One important note is that factorization of `N` has only small prime factors, all of them are 32-bit in size (maybe 64-bit at most, for sure).

I wonder if having factorization of `N` and also the fact that factors are small, can it help somehow solving the task?

Of course instead of implementing my own division first I tried to use highly-optimized [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library for this task, but it (as far as I know) doesn't use the fact that `N` is factorized already.

Can anyone suggest if I'm about to implement my own function for this, just to figure out experimentally if it will be faster than GMP's, then what kind of algorithm should I use?

I figured out that there are 3 algorithms that can be used here 1) [Long Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), which is a school-grade algorithm. 2) [Barrett Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm). 3) [Montgomery Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/montgomery-reduction-algorithm).

Actually I don't know any other algorithms. Can you suggest other? Both Barrett and Montgomery reductions can help only if same prime factor repeats many times, otherwise single-time division is not worth precomputation that is needed for Barrett and Montgomery.

Also Barrett/Montgomery reductions still need one-time computing `4^Ceil(Log2(N)) / PrimeDivisor`. So they don't save you from doing Long Division algorithm.

Definitely for Long Division algorithm I will be using `2^64` as a base instead of base `10` (as in school).

I already implemented my own experimental library with Long Division and all other integer arithmetics algorithms plus elliptic curve arithmetics too. Right now it is generic and hence not faster than GMP. Now I need special division algo that can be at least several times faster than GMP.

Sure that in Long Division I can use Montgomery and Barrett, because at each step it needs short division (128 bit integer divided by 64 bit integer) if it give any boost.

Also at each step of Long Division I can use [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) or [Number Theoretic Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general)) for doing multiplication.

Above are the only optimizations that I know about. Are there any other optimizations possible? Maybe FFT can be used for directly doing division (not just for multiplication)?

Comment: I suggest you first get your algorithm to produce the correct result, no matter how slow it runs. Then run a profiler on it and see where the slow parts are that you need to pay attention to. Hard to give advice on performance without seeing actual code

Comment: @EyalK. Current problem is not how to optimize what I have. I already have generic code. But it is not faster than GMP's generic variant, it is obvious. There is no point to optimze speed of my current algorithm, because generic solution will not be faster than GMP. The problem here is how to implement really fast algorithm using fact that factorization is avialable. Also maybe someone can tell if FFT-based techniques of division is available. I don't need solution that will be just 2 times faster than GMP, I need some special algo that will be 10-20 times faster if factorization helps.

Comment: You should remove the "performance" tag and add FORTRAN.  FORTRAN has always been efficient with numbers.  There may be a C++ library that you could use.  If not FORTRAN, the Algol language is also good at number crunching.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews By adding `performance` tag I meant that I need some algorithm that is performant, particularly that is faster than regular methods (like GMP) that don't take into account factorization of N. I didn't mean by this tag that somebody should help me doing minor optimizations in my existent code. In other words I need some brilliant ideas for good and performant algorithm. Maybe Fortran actually has such factor-based division.

Comment: @Arty: I said to get rid of performance so you can add more language tags.  Questions should only have one language tag, unless they are mixing languages.  For example, Python and C++ tags would mean that you are calling C++ from Python or calling Python from C++.  Otherwise, the single language tag should be the one you are using for development.  You may want to consider using a language that has support for your math requirements or an efficient library for your math needs.

Comment: I you need zillions of decimals I doubt any algo to be better (efficent, fast) than simple long division. Having factorization doesn't seem to me an inprovement, because it doesn't avoid the calculations to get such huge number of digits and merge the partial results.

Comment: @Ripi2 For example for multiplication there exists FFT (Fourier) which achieves `O(N Log(N))` time, which is much better than `O(N^2)` school-grade algorithm, which is a very huge improvements if you have Tera-bit numbers. But FFT is only fast for large numbers. Maybe similarly for long division there exists really fast algorithm that is much faster than naive Long Division, but which is fast only for really large numbers. I just don't know if such exists, but not so long time ago I also didn't know about FFT, but yet it existed. So waiting for Math/Algo gurus to reply!

Comment: You may find better Math gurus at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the distribution of factors? Do small factors like 2, 3, 5, etc. repeat often? If yes, you could count them and for each compute power instead of many multiplications.

Comment: @dankal444 Non-prime factors are uniformly distributed random numbers up to 2^45 in value. Of course I can pre-factor them quite fast further till there are only prime numbers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Fortran was fast because it assumes aliasing never occurs. With the introduction of `restrict` in C and similar extensions in C++ that advantage is no longer true

Answer (score 5):

### General Idea

The fact that `N` can be factorized in small integers can help. Indeed, this means `N = a1 * a2 * ... * an`. Thus, `1/N = 1/(a1 * a2 * ... * an) = (1/a1) * (1/a2) * ... * (1/an)`.

The thing is computing `1/a` for many factor `a` can be faster than computing `1/N`. Indeed:

- the *period of the decimal/binary expansion* of `1 / a` should be far smaller than `1 / N` since `log2(a)` is much smaller than `log2(N)` meaning that the exact representation of `1/a` can be stored in a very compact way and very quickly;
- the reciprocal of the factors can be computed independently, so in **parallel**;
- when a factor is used *multiple times* in the factorization of N, its costly reciprocal can be computed only once;
- *multiplying numbers should be much faster* than computing a reciprocal or a division.
- the final multiplication-based reduction can be done in parallel using a pair-wise reduction strategy.

However, there is a catch: this method requires a lot of multiplications since there is a lot of factors, and although they can be mostly computed in parallel, this is still a quite expensive computation (especially the last multiplication which is hard to execute in parallel). Thus, I am not sure the method is much faster than the very optimized method implemented in GMP, but it's certainly worth a try.

---

### Notes

It is probably better to multiply numbers of the same size together or even  to multiply first numbers with the smallest decimal/binary expansion periods together (in order to minimize the size of the symbolic representation of the computed reciprocal resulting in a smaller memory footprint and faster multiplications).

There are about 200 millions of prime numbers fitting in a 32-bit, but most factors of `N` should fit in 16-bits (since smaller factors are much more frequent) and there are only about 6500 prime numbers fitting in 16-bits, so their reciprocal could be **precomputed** if you plan to compute multiple reciprocals of different `N`.

You can use an [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm to efficiently compute the reciprocal of `p^e` when `e` is big. Such a term appear frequently in the exponential form of the prime decomposition of `N` when `N` is big.

You can truncate the period of the decimal/binary expansion if it is bigger than the final floating-point number. This will probably impact the accuracy of the method though. I think at least some additional digits are certainly needed to get an exact result (especially due to the many multiplications applied).

For the last multiplications involving huge symbolic representations, you can generate big floating-point numbers and provide them to GMP so it can use a very optimized implementation (typically based on Fast-Fourrier transforms).

---

### Example

Here is an example with a small `N = 307230` using a decimal representation for sake of clarity (the period of the decimal expansion is underlined):

```
1/307230 = 0.0000032548904729355857175406047586498714318263190443641571461120333300784428603977476157927285746834619015070142889691761872213
              ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

307230 = 2 * 3 * 5 * (7^2) * 11 * 19

1/2 = 0.50
         -
1/3 = 0.3
        -
1/5 = 0.20
         -
1/7 = 0.14285714
          ------
1/11 = 0.090
          --
1/19 = 0.0526315789473684210
          ------------------

k1 = ((1/2) * (1/3)) * ((1/5) * (1/11)) = 0.0030
                                          --

k2 = k1 * (1/19) = 0.000159489633173843700
                        ------------------

k3 = (1/7)^2 = 0.0204081632653061224489795918367346938775510
                  ------------------------------------------

1/N = k2 * k3
```

For the final multiplication, you can use an exact algorithm or a fast approximation with GMP.

Comment: I'm one of the upvotes but suspect that this will lose to `mpn_invertappr` due to the precision requirements on the intermediate results.

Comment: UpVoting. Thanks for good answer. Will probably approve soon, giving some time for other answers. Have two questions regarding your solution - `1)` How to prove that it is guaranteed enough to have reciprocal of the number till just single period, so that very final multiplication result will be exact, that it will be exactly same as if to multiply with more than period digits (e.g. two periods)? `2)` How to find period with guarantee? For example if you get first digits something like `0.123456456456` what is the guarantee that period is `456` and not longer? Also does any `1/N` have period?

Comment: The length of the period of `1/a` is up to `a-1`, for example the reciprocal of 375292573 (a prime) has a binary period of length 375292572. So this is probably not going to work.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Do you know if there is a guaranteed and fast way to find out exact length of period? Because if I calculate a number digit by digit and have something like `0.123456456456` I can't guarantee that `456` is already a period, because afterwards may go some other digits. Besides checking all `a-1` bits as you said for `1/a` how else can I find out period?

Comment: @Arty The length of the period of 1/a is the [multiplicative order of 2 mod a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) (2 being the base; for base 10 fractions you need the order of 10 mod a). [This](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) is a multiplicative order calculator in many languages (not guaranteed to be fast).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Is period length always exactly equal to mul-order of `2 mod a` (or `10 mod a`)? Or maybe mul order is multiple of period size or something like this? Do you have any links to proves/theorems/wikis regarding this fact that period is equal to mul-order? Also by "period" you mean minimal length of repeated part after dot (`.`)? E.g. `0.12345678678...` has period equal to 3 (`678`)?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you answer another question - if I precompute `1/prime` up to one period, and multiply such reciprocals - will it guarantee that I get precise final answer? Meaning that if I compare to multiplication of same reciprocals but computed with many periods will I get same final result? I'm just in doubt that single period is enough to get ideal result without errors.

Comment: Yes, the period length is exactly that (if the denominator and the base are coprime, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeOrder.html). Yes, the period is the repeating part.

Comment: No, you absolutely cannot do that, try multiplying 1/7 and 1/3 (base 10) and see what happens.